# Remove quote marks around strings in .csv file

Tags: excel, windows, batch-file

I have a csv with columns containing content as follows:

"123,456" or "1.2345" see image attached for more.

I want to remove all quote marks from the csv across all columns. The quote marks will always be the first and last characters.
The file is produced daily and contains many columns. I want to run a batch or similar to remove the quote marks each day on a schedule across all columns. I am not a coder and am vaguely familiar with batch files, so prefer to use a batch if possible. I have added an image of an example of the cell content I am dealing with.

I must use .csv format. The script can either update the existing file or write a new one.

Many thanks in advance [Example csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8R4K.png)

I have webs searched and found VBA script, but really want to use a batch that I can put into a scheduler to run each day. Happy to hear alternatives, but I cant use a macro.

Comment: Your link isn't a `.csv`, but a picture of how Excel (or other spreadsheet) represents this `.csv`. Please copy-paste (a relevant part of) the content into your question  *as text*. I see a possible problem though: if your separator is a comma (which the `c` in `csv`  (Comma Separated Values) suggests), removing the quotes around `123,456` will split the one value into two, invalidating your data.

Comment: Thank you all for your responses. I understand the implications better now. Appreciate the feedback. I will consider my question answered

Comment: @SteveC, you may consider it answered, but it is still unclear, and therefore problematic for future readers. In order to have the data you have shown in your submitted image, `|"123,456"|"1,123,456"|"123456.00"|"234"|`, the csv record may look like this: `"""123,456""","""1,123,456""","""123456.00""","""234"""`. So, in order to for it to appear like this, `|123,456|1,123,456|123456.00|234|`, in your application, the actual csv record could, and IMO should, be: `"123,456","1,123,456","123456.00","234"`. In that case, some of the comments, and the currently submitted answer fails to address it!

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
rem The following settings for the directories and filenames are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately includes spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "destdir=u:\your results"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q77630104.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"

(
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%e IN ("%filename1%") DO SET "string=%%e"&CALL :process
)>"%outfile%"

GOTO :EOF

:process
:: remove quotes
SET "string=%string:"=%"
:: remove commas
SET "string=%string:,=%"
:: replace spaces with commas
SET "string=%string: =,%"
:: And report
ECHO %string%
GOTO :eof
```

**Always verify against a test directory before applying to real data.**

Note that if the filename does not contain separators like spaces, then both `usebackq` and the quotes around `%filename1%` can be  omitted.

You would need to change the values assigned to `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances. The listing uses a setting that suits my system.

I deliberately include spaces in names to ensure that the spaces are processed correctly.

I used a file named `q77630104.txt` containing some dummy data for my testing.

Produces the file defined as `%outfile%`

The parentheses around the `for` line cause the `echo`ed output of the subroutine `:process` to be redirected to the output file.

The three stages in processing the string are suggested. See `set/?` from the prompt for docco - or thousands of examples on SO.

If you don't want to execute any of the `set` commands in `:process`, simply delete it.

The consequence of running against a file containing

```
"123,456" ""1,123,456" "123456.00" "234"
```

is

```
123456,1123456,123456.00,234
```